# emacs Evil-mode cannot map "ii" to Esc

Tags: emacs, elisp, evil-mode

When in the Insert state, I would like the key combination "ii" to switch to the Normal state. I tried the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569165/how-to-map-jj-to-esc-in-emacs-evil-mode), but it does not work for "ii". It works for other combinations I have tried (i.e. "jj" and "jk") but not "ii".

Here is my .emacs.

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(require 'follow-mouse)
(turn-on-follow-mouse)
(package-initialize)
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
(require 'key-chord)
(setq key-chord-two-keys-delay 0.5)
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "ii" 'evil-normal-state)
(key-chord-mode 1)
```

**EDIT 2014-08-07 11:57 EST** I just found out that, after entering the Insert state, I need to type at least one printable character other than "i", and then the binding will work. Does anyone know why that might be?

Comment: All three combinations you listed work fine for me in GNU Emacs 24.3.1. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get the following warning on startup: "Warning (mule): `unibyte: t' is obsolete; use "coding: 'raw-text" instead."